# Why getting SQLSTATE[42S22] error on deploy

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have just finished my Symfony 7 project, and it runs fine on my PC with XAMPP. Now I've deployed it on my webserver, created the database, and have tried to run the doctrine migration in the shell. When I do so, I get the following errors:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 67:

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i_c.TABLE_NAME' in 'where clause'


In Exception.php line 28:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i_c.TABLE_NAME' in
  'where clause'


In Statement.php line 130:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i_c.TABLE_NAME' in
  'where clause'
```

I dont understand the problem, particularly because I don't have the column `i_c.TABLE_NAME`. Additionally, if I export all tables from my local database, everything works fine, although this error still shows up when I run the command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`. Specifically,  it says that the mapping files are correct, but throws this error again.

Comment: "I have just finished my Symfony 7 project, on my PC i run all with XAMPP an all works fine." Have you double checked could you migrate tables in localhost to new/fresh database (from scratch)?

Comment: No i have to check that

Comment: After that check you can be sure if in localhost all works fine, comparing to remote server.

Comment: Created a new db in localhost, changed the .env and then: php bin/console doctrine:schema:create

This worked locally without errors, i did the same online and again the error from above... i dont undestand

Comment: I didn't work too much with Symfony/Doctrine, just meant to help with debugging path. I am unfamiliar with that error message, though.

Comment: Can you clarify the following, please?

"i dont understand the problem because i dont have the colum 'i_c.TABLE_NAME'? and if i export all tables from my locale database all is working fine, but still this error is showing up? When i do the command: php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate it says The mapping files are correct, and then this error again."

Are you saying that it runs fine on your local machine, but when you run the validator, you get the error on your local machine as well?

Comment: No the error was only online. But i solved it now. It was a false db version number in my .env

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version in the .env MariaDB, and now it works.